# de-proxy twice from a Proxy object is returning zero declared fields in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, proxy-classes

```
public static <T> T initializeAndUnproxy(T entity) {
    if (entity == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        Hibernate.initialize(entity);
        entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

I have `Emp` Object inside that `Address` object and inside `Address`, `Contact` Object is present.
Somehow I'm able to get the Declared fields using Reflection of object `Address` and checking if `Contact` is Proxy Object or not, if yes then converting them using above code but not getting anything in Declared fields.

It's like converting proxy object from a converted proxy object is giving me zero declared fields.